# dirtyPropertyNames "cannot resolve symbol" by IntelliJ

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA for a Grails Project. Running Grails 2.3.5. When using dirtyPropertyNames on a domain class, IntelliJ gives me a warning, "Cannot resolve symbol 'dirtyPropertyNames'"

Here is my code:

```
def getDirtyProperties(User user) {
    def dirtyProperties = user.dirtyPropertyNames
    return dirtyProperties
}
```

What is my problem here? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a smarter IDE :)  The method is there, which you know because the code runs. It's added to the MetaClass, so it's not visible via reflection. IDEs have to have special handling for dynamic methods and apparently this one was missed.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to get this warning to go away?

Comment: You should report this as a bug in their bug tracker. I'm sure it would be easy to add awareness that this is a valid domain class method

Answer (score 1):

```
Settings -> Inspections -> Groovy -> 
                           Probable bugs -> Access to Unresolved expression
```

Uncheck that and you should be good. I won't do it for the sake of only removing the inspections because I am not sure what the impact will be for other inspections. :)